# What $\Bbb{Z}_4[x]/\langle 2x+1\rangle$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It seems $R=\Bbb{Z}_4[x]/\langle 2x+1\rangle=\{0, 1, 2, 3, x, x+1, x+2, x+3\}$.
But I got some surprised result.

1. Since $2x+1=0$, we get $2=0+2=0x+2=4x+2=2(2x+1)=2\cdot 0=0$ and $R$ has no subring which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_4$.
2. Furthermore, $0=0\cdot x=2\cdot x=-1=3=2+1=0+1=1$.

**My Question:** So $\Bbb{Z}_4[x]/\langle 2x+1\rangle\cong\{0\}$?

This question came from the Example 20.3 in Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*.
The original example is an counterexample of Kronecker's Theorem.

Comment: @marshalcraft I think you misunderstand the notation. It is the quotient ring of $\langle 2x+1\rangle$. Not the difference. 
Note that $6x+5=2x+1$ and $6x+5\in R$.
It doesn't remove $2x+1$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. But you can do it faster: $2x=-1$ squares to $0=1$, done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2x+1$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_4[x]$ since $(2x+1)^2 = 4x^2+ 4x+ 1=1$, which means that $1\in \langle 2x+1\rangle$. If an ideal $I\subset R$ contains the unit then $I=R$.

Comment: So $\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle 2x+1\rangle\cong \{0\}$ is true because $\langle 2x+1\rangle=\Bbb{Z}_4[x]$?

Comment: Yes. More generally, $a_0 + a_1 x + \dotsc + a_n x^n \in R[x]$ is a unit iff $a_0$ is a unit and $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$ are nilpotent.

Comment: @bfhaha Yes, do you agree that is enough?

Comment: @BasharSaleh Yeah! I see. Thanks. The answer is excellent.

Comment: @HeinrichD Thanks for your fast computation. Could you please tell me where did you learn the theorem. That is, $a_0+a_1 x+\cdots +a_n x^n\in R[x]$ is a unit iff $a_0$ unit and $a_1, ..., a_n$ nilpotent?

Comment: I don't remember where I learned it (this is ages ago ...), but you can find it literarally everywhere using the appropriate search keywords, also on math.stackexchange multiple times.